# Self-made calculator doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I wrote small calculator script with JS and PHP. As i saw all is correct, but in output server show me blank ('0') value. I cant find a solution for 2 hours. 
JS script, that open connection with POST method with action 'calc.php':

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlhttp;
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
  }
  function summa() {
    var how0 = document.getElementById("how0").value;
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp(); 
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'calc.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    xmlhttp.send("how0=" + encodeURIComponent(how0));
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { 
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
          document.getElementById("how").value = xmlhttp.responseText; // 
        }
      }
    };
  }
</script>
```

Form for calculating:

```
<input type="number" required name="how0" id="how0" min="100" max="999999" placeholder="100">
 <input type="number" required readonly  name="how" id="how" min="200" max="999999" placeholder="200">
  <input type="button" value="Calcul" onclick="summa()" />
```

Calc.php for checking:

```
<?php
  $a = is_numeric($_POST["how0"]);
  $a = floor($a);
if ($a>1) {
    $a = $a * 2;
}
if ($a>10000) {
    $a = $a * 3;
}
echo $a;

?>
```

Comment: Your PHP starts with $a = is_numeric($_POST["how0"]); which is going to set $a to true or false.  Don't you want to start by setting $a to $_POST["how0"] is it's numeric?

Comment: is_numeric() is a check, it returns a boolean. I believe you want (int)$_POST['how0'] ?

Comment: @DamienPirsy - Beat you by 9 seconds.  I should probably have just waited for someone to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
$a = is_numeric($_POST["how0"]);
```

Assigns the return value of [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to `$a` — e.g., `true` or `false`. Then you use `$a` as though it contained the value posted to the script, but it doesn't.

You probably meant to use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) or [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) or similar:

```
$a = intval($_POST["how0"]);
```

---

Note that unless you need to support **really** old browsers, there's no need for your `getXmlHttp` function. All vaguely-modern browsers support `new XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: thanks! but now next problem. If i write letter bigger then 10000, calcualtor make this: $a*2*3, finally $a*6. How to divide calucaltion?

Comment: @JohnDoe: That's a *different* question. Work on it for a bit, and if you can't solve it, post that question.

Comment: And a hint to solve *that* question is the use of `else if`